# Dynamically generate a table with specific rowspans in PHP?

Tags: php, html, html-table

I've been racking my brain about an easy way to generate an HTML table with rowspans with PHP that would look like this, numbers indicating each cell's rowspan:

[image: Table with 7 total rows]

I noticed that there is sort of a pattern in the rowspans if you go from left to right, top to bottom: 1,3,7,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1. I'm not sure if that matters.

Also, I wonder if it's possible to use any method for the table above for a table like this:

[image: Table with 5 total rows]

Comment: What exactly is the question? I can't see the pattern, but I'm not even sure that's what you're asking about. :) - Do you need to make those specific tables, or... I don't get it.

Comment: Sounds like an algorithm question.

Comment: Yeah, what's the problem actually? If that's exactly what you want just go ahead and write some `td` tags with approriate `rowspan`. There seems to be no need for PHP so far. Plain html.

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  If you can't express it clearly,  you probably won't get a clear answer.

Comment: Ok, what I mean more specifically is a sort of loop that would be able to build tables where the rowspan of the cell to the right spans 3 of the cells that are to the left. You could think of each example as a tree like this: [link](http://i.imgur.com/GvKoG.png) I already understand how to recursively build it as a tree, but I am having difficulty converting that into how html formats tables with rowspanned cells.

Comment: Can you provide an example data source that would be used to generate the table from?

Answer (score 0):

maybe addressing your second example first is easier, but it might be adapted to the first example.

the structure of the tables in html is obtained using the rowspan an colspan properties.
try to picture the table as a closet, the rows as drawers and cells as boxes inside those drawers.
with these properties, u can "merge" the cells throughout rows and/or columns.

my approach would be to set a minimal block with the appearance and data that you need, ie your second example, and write it down in html.

the "php-cycle-the-thing-up" part would require you to use that html "template" in the loop dropping your recordset data in the td portions of the html.

in that way, i think you might get what your looking for.

on the other side, if you need the php to create the table dynamically, and merge the cells automatically in a set pattern, or even ignoring the pattern and simply adapt the structure as the data is coming, it would probably be better to look at the structure from the end.

because of the way that tables are built with html, nesting table-tr-td, building cycles with this look is tricky. have you considered simply nesting divs?

i'm new to stackoverflow, i wanted to comment but by the time i finished this, i couldn't remove the answer nor comment the question, sorry if this didnt quite help you... :S

Answer (score 0):

write down, come up with the recursion formula for the table.  you need to come up with the math with the least number ideally ZERO conditional statements.

it's not that hard.  for a desktop, i use three columns if it detects a mobile devices, my php automatically switches to 1 or 2 columns depending upon screen size